# Accessing Case.ContactId from Case StandardController (for Controller Extension) on [New]

Tags: case, controller-extension, custom-console-components

I'm building Custom Console Component pages to display with Case detail in Service Console to display other recent cases, assets, related Contact/Account details, etc. leveraging the Case.Id that is passed to the Controller Extension.  This is fine for view/edit on existing Cases, but not on [New].

StandardController has access to ContactId, as it pulls it onto the Case detail in edit/create from the Contact, but it is not passed to the Controller extension, and in a Create() event, there is no Case.Id passed either (as it hasn't been assigned yet).  These are the only parameters that I have clear access to:

[id=5004000000eKviT (only for pre-existing Cases)],
inContextPane=true, 
isdtp=vw, nonce=f9b448c3f48a718360f5fdcdb10b14d9b3c675268a84903a9fb17f72e18c84da, sfdcIFrameOrigin=https://cs8.salesforce.com

Is there any way to access StandardController's params?

Comment: At the moment, I'll take it as given that there's no (current) way to access this -- moving on to other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to hack up a solution, but YMMV.

My requirement was to display Account related details, but it's a refactored *Case view page*, therefore it is using standard Case controller with extension.

Essentially you need a container page that checks if id is present. If not, render VF page and get the id via JS, then redirect to intended footer page. If id is already present - redirect to footer via Apex.

Container page:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/37.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var pageLoad = window.onload;
        window.onload = function() {
                if (pageLoad) {
                        pageLoad();
                }
                testGetFocusedPrimaryTabId();
        }

        function testGetFocusedPrimaryTabId() {
                 sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabObjectId(showTabId);
         }
         var showTabId = function showTabId(result) {
                 document.location.href='/apex/ConsoleFooter?accountid='+result.id;
         };
</script>
```

Container controller:

```
public with sharing class ConsoleFooterContainer {
    public pagereference redir(){
        if ( System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id') == null )
            return null;
        else
            return new pagereference ('/apex/ConsoleFooter?id=' + System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id'));
    }
}
```

Finally in my extension constructor, I am getting the accountId and doing some checks if case id is present.

```
    case current;
    if ( controller.getId() != null )
        current = [select accountid, parent.accountid
                                    from case 
                                    where id =: 
                                    controller.getId()];

    id accountId = ( current != null ) ? 
         ( current.accountId == null ) ? current.parent.accountId : current.accountId : 
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('accountid');
    // retrieve main record
    account a = [select id, name, foo__c from account where id=: accountid];
```

It's takes an extra few seconds on new case screen, but works. Let me know if you need any help! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @dzh -- I ended up creating a custom button on the Contact layout that creates a 'shell' Case (a minimal info. Case recordtype) which can be edited by selecting the correct Case recordtype and continuing.  By creating the shell case and saving it, I can then use the new Case.Id to access Account/Contact/Asset/custom object details and display/use them in the various header/footer/side panes as needed.  Your solution looks very streamlined by comparison :D  Thanks for making it available!